# R: Function to copy to clipboard on Mac/OSX?

Tags: macos, r, clipboard

I've seen a [Windows function to copy to the clipboard](http://www.johndcook.com/r_excel_clipboard.html) in `R`.  Is there an equivalent function for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the help file for [`base::connections`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/connections.html):

> Mac OS X users can use pipe("pbpaste") and pipe("pbcopy", "w") to read from and write to that system's clipboard.

Comment: I don't know anything about R, but I'm curious why `writeClipboard` and `readClipboard` aren't implemented on OS X if they're part of R's standard library.

Comment: @bames53 The functions seem to be a Windows-only extension. They're not actually documented in the online manual - the help file is actually about reading from the X11 clipboard which is the only thing R seems to be able to do by default.

Comment: I did not find this answer helpful. This answer imo is more instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547069/how-to-write-from-r-to-the-clipboard-on-a-mac?lq=1

Answer (score 8):

Yep.  Carl is exactly right.  The best way is to use pbpaste/pbcopy.

Here's a good article on the details: http://langui.sh/2010/11/14/pbpaste-pbcopy-in-mac-os-x-or-terminal-clipboard-fun/

Rob

---

10/17/2013 - Update: As of R 3.0 the kmisc package contains the read.cb() function for multi-platform clipboard usage. Referenced from @agstudy's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14547293/168689

Comment: Why not add this as a comment to Carl's answer if you're referring to it anyway?

Comment: That was a mistake.  I looked for the reply option and didn't see it.  Sorry about that :)

Comment: @Inerdial for some reason it is feature of stackoverflow that you cannot leave comments until you have 50 reputation http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment. +1 to Rob out of empathy.

Answer (score 3):

For generic clipboard-reading in Mac, the syntax would be:

```
indat<-scan(pipe("pbpaste"),what=character(),...)
```

The `...` here is just a place-holder, look up the `scan` help to see the *very* many options you have (the `scan` default is to expect a `double` variable in the `what` argument; `character` is probably safest for generic copy, or you can choose whatever is right for your case).

Similarly, for pasting into the Mac clipboard, the generic Mac syntax is

```
outdat<-"Hi There!"
cat(outdat, file=pipe("pbcopy","w"), ...)
```

Note that the nearly the same syntax should work in Windows and Linux as well; you should just replace the `pipe` calls with the generic connection name `"clipboard"`.

The Kmisc package function mentioned above only works for data frames and tabular data, not for generic copy/paste.