# R equivalent to matrix row insertion in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab

In Matlab, without any coding, I can create a matrix, open up its spreadsheet, and copy multiple columns of values from Excel and paste them into the spreadsheet. I can then right click this matrix and plot it instantly.

I've tried googling for how to do the equivalent in R, and everything seems to involve creating a function iterating over each value with a for loop. This seems a bit cumbersome, is there an equivalent simple way to do this in RStudio?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the answer is *no*. There is `fix()`, which will give you an editable spreadsheet-type object, but I don't think it will let you copy / past whole columns. There also isn't a point-click type interface; there is Rcommander, though.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can have a similar functionality by using R's integration with a *clipboard*. In particular, standard R functions that provide support for clipboard operations include **connection** functions (`base` package), such as `file()`, `url()`, `pipe()` and others, **clipboard text transfer** functions (`utils` package), such as `readClipboard()`, `writeClipboard()`, as well as **data import** functions (`base` package), which use connection argument, such as `scan()` or `read.table()`.

This functionality differs from *platform* to platform. In particular, for Windows platform, you need to use connection name `clipboard`, for Mac platform (OS X) - you can use `pipe("pbpaste")` (see [this StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9035674/2872891) for more details and alternative methods). It appears that `Kmisc` package offers a *platform-independent* approach to that functionality, however, I haven't used it so far, so, can't really confirm that it works as expected. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547069/2872891) for details.

The following code is a simplest example of how you would use the above-mentioned functionality:

```
read.table("clipboard", sep="\t", header=header, ...)
```

An explanation and further examples are available in [this blog post](http://alandgraf.blogspot.com/2013/02/copying-data-from-excel-to-r-and-back_24.html). As far as *plotting* the imported data goes, RStudio not only allows you to use standard R approaches, but also adds an element of **interactivity** via its bundled `manipulate` package. See [this post](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551906-Interactive-Plotting-with-Manipulate) for more details and examples.